# Solutions of $x\ln x=u$ is called $x(u)$, show $\frac{u}{\ln u}<x\leq (1+1/e)\frac{u}{\ln u}$. Here $u>e$

Tags: calculus, limits

Solutions of $x\ln x=u$ is called $x(u)$, show $\frac{u}{\ln u}<x\leq (1+1/e)\frac{u}{\ln u}$. Here $u>e$.

I could just see $x\ln x$ is strictly increasing, so $\lim_{u\to\infty}x(u)=+\infty$. How to prove this exact control?

Next, how to show $x(u)\sim \frac{u}{\ln u}$ as $u\to+\infty$?

Comment: Are you supposed to know about Lambert function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = x \ln(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[1, \infty)$ with $f(e) = e$, so that $u > e$ implies $x > e$. Then $u = x \ln(x) > x$ and therefore
$$
\frac{u}{\ln(u)} < \frac{u}{\ln(x)} = x \, .
$$

For the other direction we use the convexity of
$$ 
g(u) = e^u \ge g(1) + (u-1)g'(1) = e u
$$
so that
$$
 x^{1/e} = e^{\ln(x) / e} \ge \ln(x) 
$$
and therefore
$$
\left(1 + \frac 1e \right) \frac{u}{\ln(u)} = \left(1 + \frac 1e\right) \frac{x \ln(x)}{\ln(x \ln(x))}
= x \frac{\ln(x) + \ln(x^{1/e})}{\ln(x) + \ln(\ln(x))} \ge x \, .
$$
Equality holds if and only if $x=e^e$, $u=e^{e+1}$.

In order to show that $x(u)\sim \frac{u}{\ln (u)}$ for $u \to \infty$ we need to show that, given $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
 x(u) < (1+\epsilon) \frac{u}{\ln (u)}
$$
for sufficiently large $u$. A simple calculation shows that this is equivalent to
$$
 \frac{\ln(\ln(x(u)))}{\ln(x(u))} < \epsilon 
$$
and that is true for large $u$ because the left-hand side converges to zero if $u \to \infty$.